# Can i use the Image in CustomCallOut view react-native-maps

Tags: image, react-native, react-native-maps

I tried with customCallout from react-native-maps library but it is not working on iOS simulator.
in my issue what I was implementing the react-native-map library and i want to display the image in my custom-callout view (custom callout is annotation view in map library which show popup after clicking the marker) but if i put the image tag in that view image is not displaying.

```
<Callout alphaHitTest tooltip>
        <CustomCallout>
                 <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
                      <Icon name="map-marker" size={30} />
                      <Text style={{ width: "50%" }}>
                        {this.state.currentAddress}   //coordinates
                      </Text>
                 <Text>
                        <Image
                          source={require("./../assets/images/profile.png")}
                        />
                      </Text>
                </View>
            </CustomCallout>
</Callout>
```